# Overloaded constructor in Python from C++ perspective

Tags: c++, python

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>
class SomeClass
{
  int someInteger;
  float someFloat;
public:
  SomeClass(int someInteger_)
  {
    // do something for int
    std::cout << "Int constructor\n";
  }
  SomeClass(float someFloat_)
  {
    // do something for float
    std::cout << "Float constructor\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomeClass a(2);
  SomeClass b(2.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

Objects of class SomeClass are differently created when float or int arguments for constructors are passed. There is similar class in Python:

```
class SomeClass:
    someInteger = 0
    someFloat = 0.0
    def __init__(self, value):
        # I want to do different things when int or float is passed
        print value

a = SomeClass(2)
b = SomeClass(2.0)
```

General question is - how to make function behavior dependent from types of passed arguments?

Comment: BTW, in that C++ code `someInteger` and `someFloat` are non-static data members. In your python code they are static (python class members).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> isinstance(1, float)
False
>>> isinstance(1.1, float)
True
>>> isinstance(1.1, int)
False
```

Or for you constructor:

```
def __init__(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        # int constructor
    elif isinstance(value, float):
        # float constructor
    else:
        raise TypeError, 'Unexpected type'
```